# Div content overlapping

Tags: html, css, layout, overlapping

I've got the following markup and styling: http://cssdesk.com/dtYQc.
My problem is that when I zoom page smaller in *Mozilla Firefox/IE* content of `.employee-card` overlaps div borders at the bottom. And in *Chrome* only `Details` link overlaps.

Also how do I fix the markup (`sidebar` is positioned incorrectly when zooming): http://cssdesk.com/A7dzX.

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't find any of what you're saying in the first demo

Comment: That's strange. In the `cssdesk` you can make a full minimization. `Details` link's going down. The same effect I achieve with Firefox.. with smaller zoom ratio.

Answer (score 2):

As to the second question - add to `#sidebar` in its style `position:absolute`, then you can change margin so it will match to where you want it to be.(`margin: 60px 0;`). It will not be positioned incorrectly after you're doing that.